# why path = os.Getenv("GOMOD"), path = "" in the project?

Tags: go, go-modules

I don't known why I can not get the path value. may be there something error or other,
path = os.Getenv("GOMOD")
// path is ""

1.project go env:

```golang
....
GOMOD="/home/lu/go/gowork/work/gt/go.mod"
...
```

2. system go env:

```golang
...
GOMOD=""
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve it:
in golang code,

```golang
import "github.com/dreamlu/gt/tool/file/file_func"
path = file_func.ProjectPath()
```

print the path = "/home/lu/go/gowork/work/gt/go.mod"